# Azure data sync troubleshooting upload failures

Tags: azure, azure-data-sync

In the Azure data sync logs every sync I get a warning message that claims that 4 upload records have failed. However there is no detail associated with the log record, so I have no idea what table these 4 records are missing from or what the PK is of the records that is causing the problem.

Is there a way to troubleshoot this issue? Perhaps by querying the tables data sync adds to the hub/member databases?

In the event log in the on premise server, I'm seeing a stream of events similar to this:

> id:SyncServiceTask_ExceptionProcessingRequest, rId:,
>   sId:b375b9d2-4596-4a69-9b87-71dc351108bc,
>   taskId:e63d1aa8-1bf6-4bd5-b877-94b623004f89,
>   e:'Type=System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.SqlAzureDataSync.ClientServerCommon.DssFaultException&#44;
>   Microsoft.SqlAzureDataSync.ClientServerCommon&#44;
>   Version&#61;4.3.0.0&#44; Culture&#61;neutral&#44;
>   PublicKeyToken&#61;31bf3856ad364e35]],Message=Object reference not set
>   to an instance of an object.
>   ,Source=Microsoft.SqlAzureDataSync.SyncAgentServiceApi,StackTrace=
>
>   at
>   Microsoft.SqlAzureDataSync.SyncAgentServiceApi.SyncAgentServiceApi.CompleteDataSyncTask(String
>   responseXml&#44; Guid taskId&#44; Guid tracingId)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlAzureDataSync.SyncControllerLib.SyncControllerTaskBase.CompleteTask(Guid
>   taskId&#44; BaseResponse response),',
>   eType:'Type=System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.SqlAzureDataSync.ClientServerCommon.DssFaultException,
>   Microsoft.SqlAzureDataSync.ClientServerCommon,
>   Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]', eMessage:'Message=Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object. ', eTypeInner:,
>   eMessageInner: